# Single Sign on Using Ldap and Weblogic Server (Java)

Tags: java, single-sign-on

I have a newbie questions to ask the experts out there. Currently I am able to get SSO with `Active directory` and `Bea Weblogic` server.

I am able to retrieve the login person id using  `httpreq.getUserPrincipal()`.

But I need to be able to retrieve other attribute from AD such as `email`, `department` etc.

Is it possible to retrieve those informations from cookies?
Do I need to configure any thing at AD or Bea Servers for it to works.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create your own Weblogic Authentication provider, which would connect to AD, find your user, get all attributes you need and put them into your Security Principal. Then you can get this info from Principal in your servlets.